# Can't write to EN_AA register but can write others: nRF24L01+PA+LNA

Tags: spi, nrf24l01

I have an ATMega328P on a PCB with an LED connected along with a nRF24L01+PA+LNA radio module. The LED is the only easy way for me to observe data from the microcontroller, so in my code I blink it depending on the read value of the registers. Here it is:

```c
#define F_CPU 8000000

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/sfr_defs.h>
#include <avr/portpins.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#include "nrf24l01-mnemonics.h"

void spiInit();
uint8_t spiTransfer(uint8_t data);
uint8_t nrfReadReg(uint8_t regAddress);
uint8_t nrfWriteReg(uint8_t regAddress, void *data, size_t length);

#define statusLedPin _BV(PB0)
#define nrfCePin _BV(PB1)
#define nrfCsnPin _BV(PB2)

int main(void) {
    spiInit();
    
    DDRB |= statusLedPin | nrfCePin | nrfCsnPin;
    PORTB |= statusLedPin | nrfCePin | nrfCsnPin;
    
    uint8_t data;
    
    data = _BV(PWR_UP);
    nrfWriteReg(CONFIG, &data, 1);
    
    _delay_ms(5);
    
    data = 0;
    nrfWriteReg(EN_AA, &data, 1);
    _delay_ms(5);
    nrfWriteReg(SETUP_RETR, &data, 1);
    
    _delay_ms(5);
    
    data = _BV(MASK_TX_DS) | _BV(MASK_MAX_RT) | _BV(PWR_UP);
    nrfWriteReg(CONFIG, &data, 1);

    _delay_ms(5);
    

    // led will blink if EN_AA is at it's default value, and it always does
    uint8_t a = nrfReadReg(EN_AA);
    while (1) {
        if (a == 0b00111111){
            PORTB ^= statusLedPin;
        }
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}

void spiInit() {
    SPCR |= _BV(MSTR);
    SPCR |= _BV(SPE);
    DDRB |= _BV(PB3) | _BV(PB4) | _BV(PB5);
    SPCR &= ~_BV(CPOL);
    SPCR &= ~_BV(CPHA);
    SPCR &= ~_BV(SPR0);
    SPCR &= ~_BV(SPR1);
    SPSR |= _BV(SPI2X);
    SPCR &= ~_BV(DORD);
}

uint8_t spiTransfer(uint8_t data) {
    SPDR = data;
    while (!(SPSR & _BV(SPIF)));
    return SPDR;
}

uint8_t nrfSendCommand(uint8_t command, void* data, size_t length) {
    PORTB &= ~nrfCsnPin;
    PORTB &= ~nrfCePin;

    uint8_t spiResponse = spiTransfer(command);
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    ((uint8_t*)data)[i] = spiTransfer(((uint8_t*)data)[i]);

    PORTB |= nrfCePin;
    PORTB |= nrfCsnPin;

    return spiResponse;
}

uint8_t nrfWriteReg(uint8_t regAddress, void* data, size_t length) {
    return nrfSendCommand(W_REGISTER | regAddress, data, length);
}

uint8_t nrfReadReg(uint8_t regAddress) {
    PORTB &= ~nrfCsnPin;
    PORTB &= ~nrfCePin;
    
    spiTransfer(regAddress);
    uint8_t data = spiTransfer(NOP);
    
    PORTB |= nrfCePin;
    PORTB |= nrfCsnPin;
    
    return data;
}
```

The problem is that the EN_AA register is always its default value. No matter how many times I try to write to it, how I try to write to it, or how many different ChatGPT programs I copy and paste, it stays the same. On the other hand, the above script is able to write to the CONFIG and SETUP_RETR registers and read the values successfully.

From this I assume that my SPI and register write/read functions work correctly, but for some reason I just can't change the EN_AA register.

EDIT:
I found that the CE pin was shorted to 3.3v and was also connected to the 5v ATMega, which really messed up power to the nRF which was 4.5v among other things. This is probably related to the problem and I will do more testing.